# How to disable textbox date_picker

Tags: jquery

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New First Cut off*</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control date_picker" id="n_first_cut" name='n_first_cut'>
</div>
```

`$('n_first_cut').prop('disabled', true);`

Can I know how to disable my textbox but it never disables it's because of date_picker class?

`$('n_first_cut').removeClass("date_picker");`

if I remove date_picker class nothing happens too

Comment: You have to use the id selector `#` so it looks like `$('#n_first_cut')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change in your existing code adds just '#'. show below code line.

`$('#n_first_cut').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to give `#` in your code.

```
$('#n_first_cut').removeClass("date_picker");
```